# Legacy Cywgin Installation Using Cywgin Time Machine Failing (Unable to get setup-2.ini)

Tags: cygwin

I am attempting to download an older version of Cygwin (1.7.16) in order to compile an open source project (Dummynet - windows port). 
The only way i found of doing so is by using a project known as Cygwin Time Machine. 
In order to use this i downloaded the cygwin 1.7 installer from 'ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/setup/1.7/setup-1.7.exe', and when prompted for a download site, added 'ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2012/08/20/222043'. However, the download fails with the following error :

> Unable to get setup-2.ini from
>   ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2012/08/20/222043

Im looking for help in getting past this error, or any other alternative way of installing Cywgin 1.7.16 (Aug 20, 2012).

Comment: Please note: The **Cygwin Time Machine** has moved! Please view the new site at [http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html].  Also note that the old FTP urls have been converted to HTTP urls with a different hostname prefix such as **(http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/...)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Admin at Cygwin Time Machine was kind enough to point me to the solution. The issue can be resolved by downloading the cygwin setup exe from cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe and starting it with the -X option. Once started, one may choose any cygwin 1.7.* snapshot url from the cygwin time machine site and add that as the mirror to download and install cygwin from.